# How to use 'or' in Java?

Tags: java, boolean-operations

I'm quite new to Java, and can't figure out how to use 'or'. What is the Java equivalent? 
I've already tried `&&` and `||` but eclipse does not recognise it.

This is part of my code:

```
if (action.equals ("run") || ("sprint")) {
    System.out.println("you ran");
}
else {
    System.out.println("else");
}
```

Comment: The bitwise OR or conditional OR ?

Comment: `&&` means `AND`. You are searching for `||`

Comment: Post some code maybe?  It changes depending on context.

Comment: This is an _extremely_ basic skill every programmer needs to know.

Comment: _eclipse does not recognise it_ Then you are using it were you shouldn't.

Comment: `(turkey && stuffing) || (potatoes && gravy)`

Comment: You were downvoted because of your impressive lack of research effort. I'd suggest that you read the FAQ.

Comment: `if (action.equals("run") || action.equals("sprint")) {
    System.out.println("you ran");
}
else {
    System.out.println("else");
}`

Answer (score 4):

> I've already tried && and || but eclipse does not recognise it.

That's very strange, but just to cover the basics: Let's assume you have the variable `a` and it contains the value `5`. Then:

```
if (a == 5 || a == 7)
```

...will be true, because the first part of the expression (`a == 5`) is true. So the statement "`a` equals 5 **or** `a` equals 7" is true.

The `||` operator can only be used, in Java, where a boolean (true or false) expression is expected, such as in an `if` statement like the above. So pretty much in an `if` or a conditional operator (that `?...:` thing, sometimes called the ternary operator).

---

Re your edit, the problem is that both sides of your `||` operator aren't true or false ("boolean") expressions. Your statement:

```
if (action.equals ("run") || ("sprint")){
```

breaks down like this:

```
if (
   action.equals ("run")
|| // ("or")
   ("sprint")
)
```

the second part of that isn't a true/false, it's a string. The correct way to express that in Java (or nearly any other programming language) is:

```
if (action.equals ("run") || action.equals ("sprint")){
```

Now both sides of the `||` result in true/false exprssions:

```
if (
   action.equals ("run")
|| // ("or")
   action.equals ("sprint")
)
```

The reason for this is that the second part may have nothing whatsoever to do with `action`, and so the compiler can't assume you mean to re-use it in the second part of the expression. You might, for instance, want to use `||` with two completely unrelated things:

```
if (action.equals("run") || somethingElse.equals("run")) {
```

Comment: when they say eclipse doesn't recognize the expression it is most likely because it is being used out of its proper location

Answer (score 0):

Ok. `("sprint")` is not a Boolean expression. Since a `if` condition expects a Boolean expression your code returns an error. You should change the line with:

```
if (action.equals ("run") || action.equals("sprint")){
```

Answer (score 0):

The `equals` method returns a boolean and the || operator wants two booleans on each side.

You're doing an `action.equals("run")` on one side but then a `("sprint")` on the other which isn't a boolean expression.

Change your code like so:

`if (action.equals("run") || action.equals("sprint")){`